# How to programmatically add a map bookmark from my app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, maps, location, bookmarks

Considering I have the coordinates of a location how can I programmatically add a map bookmark(to the maps app) when tapping an in app "add to bookmarks" button?

Thanks